# Issue with secure boot and official kernel 5.15.0-56

Tags: boot, kernel, secure-boot

I got a new ThinkPad L13 and I decided to install Ubuntu on it. Installation went fine until I had to install the kernel 5.15.0-56, which is a requirement for an application. 5.15.0-56 installs without problems but it doesn't boot because of "bad shim". The kernel is signed and it's the official one from ubuntu. How can I fix this?